# Protege OntoGraf Plug-in is not work

Tags: plugins, graph, ontology, classnotfoundexception, protege

I am developing ontology in Protege IDE, but plug-in OntoGraf does not work fo me. Please help me with this issue. Below you would see stacktrace:

```
./run.sh
Starting Protege 4 OWL Editor (Version 4.1.0, Build = 220)
Platform:
    Java: JVM 1.6.0_18-b18 Memory: 506M
    Language: ru, Country: RU
    Framework: Apache Software Foundation (1.5)
    OS: linux (2.6.32-5-686)
    Processor: x86
Installed plugin Pellet Reasoner Plug-in
Installed plugin The Protege 4 OWL Editor
Installed plugin Owlviz Plug-in
Installed plugin HermiT Reasoner
Installed plugin OntoGraf Plug-in
Installed plugin Matrix Views
Installed plugin Factplusplus Plug-in
Installed plugin Dlquery
Installed plugin The OWL API
Using OWL API version 3.2.2.1789
Rebuilding entity indices...
... rebuilt in 66 ms
loading Anonymous-1 from file:/home/moskvin/ontologies/Ontology1292782662967/Ontology1292782662967.owl
Setting active ontology to <http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/Ontology1292782662967.owl><http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/Ontology1292782662967.owl>
Rebuilding entity indices...
... rebuilt in 1 ms
... active ontology changed
Setting active ontology to <http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/Ontology1292782662967.owl><http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/Ontology1292782662967.owl>
Rebuilding entity indices...
... rebuilt in 0 ms
... active ontology changed
Error logged
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/dc/path/PathException
        at ca.uvic.cs.chisel.cajun.graph.node.DefaultGraphNodeStyle.<init>(DefaultGraphNodeStyle.java:82)
        at ca.uvic.cs.chisel.cajun.graph.AbstractGraph.<init>(AbstractGraph.java:172)
        at ca.uvic.cs.chisel.cajun.graph.AbstractGraph.<init>(AbstractGraph.java:145)
        at ca.uvic.cs.chisel.cajun.graph.FlatGraph.<init>(FlatGraph.java:29)
        at org.protege.ontograf.common.GraphController.<init>(GraphController.java:83)
        at org.protege.ontograf.OntoGrafView.initialiseClassView(OntoGrafView.java:174)
        at org.protege.editor.owl.ui.view.cls.AbstractOWLClassViewComponent.initialiseView(AbstractOWLClassViewComponent.java:28)
        at org.protege.editor.owl.ui.view.AbstractOWLSelectionViewComponent.initialiseOWLView(AbstractOWLSelectionViewComponent.java:118)
        at org.protege.editor.owl.ui.view.AbstractOWLViewComponent.initialise(AbstractOWLViewComponent.java:61)
        at org.protege.editor.core.ui.view.View.createContent(View.java:434)
        at org.protege.editor.core.ui.view.View.createUI(View.java:214)
        at org.protege.editor.core.ui.view.View$1.hierarchyChanged(View.java:144)
        at java.awt.Component.processHierarchyEvent(Component.java:6275)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:5894)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2105)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4469)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2163)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4295)
        at java.awt.Component.createHierarchyEvents(Component.java:5124)
        at java.awt.Container.createHierarchyEvents(Container.java:1418)
        at java.awt.Container.createHierarchyEvents(Container.java:1415)
        at java.awt.Container.createHierarchyEvents(Container.java:1415)
        at java.awt.Container.createHierarchyEvents(Container.java:1415)
        at java.awt.Container.createHierarchyEvents(Container.java:1415)
        at java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1432)
        at java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1464)
        at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1416)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.setVisible(JComponent.java:2612)
        at javax.swing.JTabbedPane.fireStateChanged(JTabbedPane.java:395)
        at javax.swing.JTabbedPane$ModelListener.stateChanged(JTabbedPane.java:270)
        at javax.swing.DefaultSingleSelectionModel.fireStateChanged(DefaultSingleSelectionModel.java:133)
        at javax.swing.DefaultSingleSelectionModel.setSelectedIndex(DefaultSingleSelectionModel.java:67)
        at javax.swing.JTabbedPane.setSelectedIndexImpl(JTabbedPane.java:616)
        at javax.swing.JTabbedPane.setSelectedIndex(JTabbedPane.java:591)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI$Handler.mousePressed(BasicTabbedPaneUI.java:3639)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6105)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:5873)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2105)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4469)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2163)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4295)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4461)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4122)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4055)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2149)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2478)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4295)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:604)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:275)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:200)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:190)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:185)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:177)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.dc.path.PathException
        at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(ModuleImpl.java:814)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.access$100(ModuleImpl.java:61)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl$ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleImpl.java:1733)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
        ... 55 more
Uncaught Exception in thread AWT-EventQueue-0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/dc/path/PathException
        at ca.uvic.cs.chisel.cajun.graph.node.DefaultGraphNodeStyle.<init>(DefaultGraphNodeStyle.java:82)
        at ca.uvic.cs.chisel.cajun.graph.AbstractGraph.<init>(AbstractGraph.java:172)
        at ca.uvic.cs.chisel.cajun.graph.AbstractGraph.<init>(AbstractGraph.java:145)
        at ca.uvic.cs.chisel.cajun.graph.FlatGraph.<init>(FlatGraph.java:29)
        at org.protege.ontograf.common.GraphController.<init>(GraphController.java:83)
        at org.protege.ontograf.OntoGrafView.initialiseClassView(OntoGrafView.java:174)
        at org.protege.editor.owl.ui.view.cls.AbstractOWLClassViewComponent.initialiseView(AbstractOWLClassViewComponent.java:28)
        at org.protege.editor.owl.ui.view.AbstractOWLSelectionViewComponent.initialiseOWLView(AbstractOWLSelectionViewComponent.java:118)
        at org.protege.editor.owl.ui.view.AbstractOWLViewComponent.initialise(AbstractOWLViewComponent.java:61)
        at org.protege.editor.core.ui.view.View.createContent(View.java:434)
        at org.protege.editor.core.ui.view.View.createUI(View.java:214)
        at org.protege.editor.core.ui.view.View$1.hierarchyChanged(View.java:144)
        at java.awt.Component.processHierarchyEvent(Component.java:6275)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:5894)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2105)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4469)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2163)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4295)
        at java.awt.Component.createHierarchyEvents(Component.java:5124)
        at java.awt.Container.createHierarchyEvents(Container.java:1418)
        at java.awt.Container.createHierarchyEvents(Container.java:1415)
        at java.awt.Container.createHierarchyEvents(Container.java:1415)
        at java.awt.Container.createHierarchyEvents(Container.java:1415)
        at java.awt.Container.createHierarchyEvents(Container.java:1415)
        at java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1432)
        at java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1464)
        at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1416)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.setVisible(JComponent.java:2612)
        at javax.swing.JTabbedPane.fireStateChanged(JTabbedPane.java:395)
        at javax.swing.JTabbedPane$ModelListener.stateChanged(JTabbedPane.java:270)
        at javax.swing.DefaultSingleSelectionModel.fireStateChanged(DefaultSingleSelectionModel.java:133)
        at javax.swing.DefaultSingleSelectionModel.setSelectedIndex(DefaultSingleSelectionModel.java:67)
        at javax.swing.JTabbedPane.setSelectedIndexImpl(JTabbedPane.java:616)
        at javax.swing.JTabbedPane.setSelectedIndex(JTabbedPane.java:591)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI$Handler.mousePressed(BasicTabbedPaneUI.java:3639)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6105)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:5873)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2105)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4469)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2163)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4295)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4461)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4122)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4055)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2149)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2478)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4295)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:604)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:275)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:200)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:190)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:185)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:177)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.dc.path.PathException
        at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(ModuleImpl.java:814)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.access$100(ModuleImpl.java:61)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl$ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleImpl.java:1733)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
        ... 55 more
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately I need to use Java from Sun to use this plugin. My Linux distribution (Debian GNU/Linux 6.0) is been installed with OpenJDK, which does not contain the sun packages.
I fixed this issue when I updated links java* in directory /etc/alternatives.
For debian is simple make it with command:

```
 update-alternatives --config java
 update-alternatives --config javac
 update-alternatives --config javaws
 update-alternatives --config jar
 end etc..
```

Comment: See http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1091 for details on installing and configuring the new JRE as default.